# float при position: fixed

Tags: position, css

Здравствуйте, почему перестают работать float при задании position? Пример:

```
<div style="position: fixed;">
 <div style="float: left">
  left
 </div>
 <div style="float: right">
  right
 </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ширину нужно ставить на родителя, в котором position: fixed;

Comment: @markuper, ставил уже. <div style="width: 500px"><div style="position: fixed">...</div></div>. Ведь это правильно?

Comment: <div style="position: fixed; width: 500px;">
Внешний блок не нужен

Comment: @Barton, Спасибо!

Answer (score 1):

Для втрого блока `float: right;` делать ненадо, задайте `width` для блоков и для второго `margin-left = width` первого блока

```
    <div style="position: fixed;">
        <div style="float: left; width: 100px;">
            left
        </div>
        <div style="margin-left: 100px;">
            right
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: @Barton, это бред. Я должен сам отсчитывать пиксели до правого края. Так не пойдёт.

Comment: ок, тогда вариант @markuper вам подойдет